# Parse UNIX timestamp with timezone offset (e.g. "14232335 +0200")

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, timezone, unix-timestamp

I am trying to parse some timestamps in python. They look like this:

```
1334423456 +0200
```

where obviously the first part is a UNIX timestamp, and the second part the timezone offset in format "+HHMM"/"-HHMM". I am trying to get this into a python.datetime object.

I can use the first part with datetime.fromtimestamp:

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(s.split()[0])
```

but I have no idea how to apply the second part (timezone offset) to it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest method is to use the [`iso8601` module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601); it includes an (internal) timezone parser that handles *almost* your format; we need to insert a `:` to follow make it match ISO 8601 timezones:

```
import iso8601
stamp, tz = s.split()
timezone = iso8601.iso8601.parse_timezone(tz[:3] + ':' + tz[3:])
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(stamp)).astimezone(timezone)
```

Comment: I had to convert the "+HHMM" to "+HH:MM" manually by doing this: `s = s[:3] + ":" + s[3:]` but then it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @opatut: uhm, of course! :-) Updated the answer to pretend I knew that.